# Run command after all bash commands automatically?

Tags: linux, bash

I use an `alert` command which notifies me whenever a bash comand runs (e.g. `./long_running_task ; alert`) will send an alert whenever `long_running_task` completes. I sometimes forget to write `; alert` at the end of my commands, so I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically trigger this--like with some sort of [shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)). The [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123034/execute-command-after-every-command-in-bash) seem to only work if I want to run `alert` *before* `long_running_task`, which won't help in my case.

Is there a way to call the `alert` command *after* every shell command that I run from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you can do this by setting the [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) variable. In my bashrc, I added this line: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='alert'`.