# After command hook, execute command after/ along with every command in Bash

Tags: bash

I would like to execute a command after every command, there is [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123034/execute-command-after-every-command-in-bash) where using `trap` is suggested, but, this is not what I am looking for and there are issues on using `trap`

Issue with `trap` for this purpose, I added the following trap in `.bashrc`:

```
###########
# .bashrc #
###########

function process_command() {
  $BASH_COMMAND | grep --color -E 'ERROR|'
}
trap process_command DEBUG
```

And now for every statement, when I execute any command I am getting the output printed twice in `stdout`

Example:

```
Content of error.log
--------------------
ERROR
WARNING
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, since your `grep` pattern matches the empty string (which is part of *every* string) it prints everything twice. But what are you trying to do?

Comment: In my opinion, it does not match everything as there is a `pipe` operator, and is applied only to the output of the first command.

Comment: I am trying to highlight few words from the output of first command. In this example `ERROR` @l0b0

Comment: Well, you're running the command *twice* - once in your code and once in your trap, so you are not processing the output of the original command at all. I don't know if that is even possible.