# Logging Successful Commands

Tags: linux, bash

So, I'm really new to writing scripts but really enjoying it. For a class I am currently taking the instructor is asking that we provide a log file of all the commands we use in our labs. Up until now, I have just been doing history > file.txt. The problem with that method for me is that it is also logging a ton of my typos. I could just keep doing it that way because it doesn't affect my grade at all but I'm eager to learn as much as I can.

Anyways, I am hoping to come up with something to sort and log my successful commands as I go. I wrote a script that kinda does it but it costs me a lot of functionality. I was hoping to get some help to point me in the right direction.

```
#!/bin/bash

logger(){
read usr_command
$usr_command
exit_code=$?
if [ "$exit_code" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "yea"
else
   echo "nah"
fi
}

while true; do

logger

done
```

Obviously, I need to write instructions to pass the commands to a file once they been analyzed but what I'm really looking for is a way to do this without passing my commands through `read`. I can't seem to get the script to recognize the exit code of the commands I want because every time it runs it just catches the successful command that executes the script.

Thanks in advance for looking over my amateur skills and sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: Doable nicely in Bash 5.1. What version of Bash do you use?

Comment: Simple way is to test return of command `ls -al && echo "ls -al" >> success.log || echo "ls -al" >> fail.log` (note: if write error occurs to `success.log`, then `fail.log` will also be written (not likely to happen, but good to understand the limitations on `a && b || c`)

Answer (score 1):

In regards to lost functionality, something like [rl-wrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) might help.

Instead of making your own REPL, you could prepend a function call to each command like this:

```sh
ok() {
  "$@"
  test $? -eq 0 && echo "$*" >> successful-commands.txt
}

ok true # logged
ok false # not logged
```

In this way, your question is similar to:

- [Execute command after every command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123034/execute-command-after-every-command-in-bash)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/126737/make-gnome-terminal-show-the-command-running-as-title.